# How to unwrap optional NSDictionary

Tags: swift

I cannot unwrap an optional NSDictionary. I am using NSDictionary because that is what I am returned when loading a plist from a file path.

```
var dict: NSDictionary? = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: getFontPath())

assert(dict != nil, "Top level dictionary from plist can't be nil")

var fontArray = dict!objectForKey("fonts") as [NSDictionary]
```

The compiler is not recognizing dict! as an unwrap - tells me I should separate sequences by a ;

What is the problem and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the attribute accessor (ie, the dot) after the exclamation point:

```
var fontArray = dict!.objectForKey("fonts") as [NSDictionary]
                     ^
```

Depending on what you're doing, it might make more sense to use `if let`, eg:

```
if let unwrappedDict = dict as? NSDictionary {

}
```

Comment: Yikes how could I miss that. Also I was trying to do the conditional unwrap but couldn't figure out the syntax when using 'as' so you solved that problem too

Comment: And you can use `dict!["fonts"]` instead of `objectForKey`.